Characterizing the constancy of the row rank of a matrix function when the rank is everywhere less than the maximum
In the theory of public economics I have occasion to examine the behavior of the following "matrix function":
\begin{equation*}
Z(x) = 
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & \cdots & 1 \\
g_{11} (x_1) & g_{21}(x_2) &\cdots & g_{n1} (x_n) \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
g_{1k} (x_1) & g_{2k} (x_2) & \cdots & g_{nk} (x_n) 
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation*}
where $x \in \mathscr{S} \equiv R^n \bigcap \{ x : \sum \limits_{i=1}^n x_i = 1,\; x_i > 0, 1 \leq i \leq n \}$ and where we assume $n > k+1$. Here, each $g_{ij}$ can be taken to be a smooth, strictly positive function; further, for each $l, \; 1 \leq l \leq k$, I know I can find at least one point $x^l \in \mathscr{S}$ such that $(g_{1l}(x^l_1),\ldots,g_{nl}(x^l_n))$ is a scalar multiple of the first row (i.e. all components are equal).
Question: I am interested in the (row) rank $\rho (Z(x))$ of $Z(x)$ as $x$ varies over $\mathscr{S}$ and whether or not that rank can be constant. Now it is clear that we can have $\rho(Z(x)) \equiv 1$ but that we cannot (because of the assumption in the last sentence of the previous paragraph) have $\rho(Z(x)) \equiv k+1$. So my question is: Can $\rho(Z(x)) \equiv r$ for some $r,\; 1 < r < k+1$?
My sense is that the answer is no, and initially this seemed like it would be a simple thing to prove. But, of course, the more I got into a possible proof the more difficulties I encountered. The way I approached things was to try to reduce the problem to that of dealing with an $r \times r$ matrix by considering submatrices of each $Z(x)$. If I could prove that $\rho (Z(x)) \equiv r$ on $\mathscr{S}$ implied that there was an $r \times r$ submatrix $Z_r(x)$ such that $\rho (Z_r(x)) \equiv r$ on $\mathscr{S}$ then I would have a contradiction. Unfortunately I have tried multiple approaches to show this implication without success.
One was to use the fact that at each point of $\mathscr{S}$ at least one of the finite number of $r \times r$ submatrices must have nonvanishing determinant, yielding a neighborhood of that point on which this is true. Unfortunately there is no guarantee that any of the rows of $Z_r(x)$ becomes a linear multiple of the first on that neighborhood. I've also tried using sequences in $\mathscr{S}$ on which there is some fixed submatrix with non-vanishing determinant, but to no avail.
Am I pursuing this the wrong way? Am I making it too difficult (I have been accused of this many times in the past)? Is it in fact possible for $\rho (Z(x)) \equiv r$ for some $r$ strictly between $1$ and $k+1$? Any ideas or pointers appreciated, and apologies if this is a question that is really simple to answer.
Edit: Ted Shifrin asked if I had experimented with small values for $n$ and $k$ and indeed I have. Specifically, for $n=4$ and $k=2$ I don't believe the rank of $Z(x)$ can be identically two. Of course this is just one specific case, but it's the genesis for my thinking and approach to the problem.
Consider a point $x^1 \in \mathscr{S}$ which is on the boundary of the (closed) set of all points $x$ for which the second row of $Z(x)$ is a scalar multiple of the first. Then, in order for the rank of $Z(x^1)$ to equal two the third row must be linearly independent of the first two. I of course have to be careful but I think it should be true there then exists a small enough neighborhood $V$ of $x^1$ and a point $x^\prime \in V$ such that the third row of $Z(x^\prime)$ is not a scalar multiple of either the first or second row and the second row is not a scalar multiple of the first, which would make the rank of $Z(x^\prime)$ three, a contradiction. I will still need to prove this last claim but at least you get an idea of my train of thought.

Is there a reason you’re reversing row and column indices compared to their standard usage? You then seem to be comparing the $l$th column to the first row. This makes no sense, as they have different numbers of entries.

I actually thought about reversing the numbering but this was the way the rows/columns were indexed in the original research. The first index is the agent, the second the good. If you think reversing would make it easier for others to understand I can do that. I don't want to give people trying to help me out any additional work to do. :)

Now I realize  I misunderstood the notation. I withdraw my second complaint.  Why do you suspect the row rank cannot be arbitrary?  Rank is lower semicontinuous, but not continuous, anyhow. Have you tried some examples with small $n$ and $k$?

Actually, I have, for $n=4,;k=2$ (that's usually the first thing I do when tackling a problem like this). I don't think the rank can be constant at two in this case. Of course even if I'm right that's just one example, but my thinking is too long for a comment so I'll edit the question. BTW, thanks for your posts prodding me.
